# How to pass the right number of arguments into Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to delete an entry in the interview_participant table via the interviews_participants controller. I've got through a number of issues but am getting stuck on an error:

ArgumentError in InterviewsParticipantsController#destroy "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

The model for interview_participant is...

```
class InterviewParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interview
  belongs_to :participant

  attr_accessible :interview_id, :participant_id
```

and the destroy method in the interview_participants controller is

```
  def destroy
    @interview_participant = InterviewParticipant.where(:interview_id => params[:interview_id]).where(:participant_id => params[:participant_id])
    @interview_participant.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to interview_participant_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I would like to be able to remove a participant from an interview by deleting the row in the interview_participant table through this destroy method. In the "show" view for an interview I am isting the participants and would like a button to remove a participant. In the show view for an interview I have...

```
<p>
  <b>Participants</b>
  <% @interview.participants.each do |participant| %>
    <dd><%= participant.name %></dd>
    <dd><%= button_to( "Remove", {
                     :controller => "interview_participants",
                     :action => "destroy",
                     :interview_id => @interview.id,
                     :participant_id => participant.id },
                     :method => :delete,
                     :confirm => "Are you sure?"
                     ) %></dd>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

I think I am passing the right arguments becasue my URL is `/interview_participants/1?interview_id=3&participant_id=2` (when I press the button next to for participant 2 and interview 3). But I get the "wrong number of arguments" error in my browser. I've been looking at this for several hours and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Your model class should be named in the singular, `InterviewParticipant`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on my part. It is indeed called InterviewParticipant. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've done a proper cut and paste into the text above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your query:

```
@interview_participant = InterviewParticipant.where(:interview_id => params[:interview_id]).where(:participant_id => params[:participant_id])
```

Is returning an array since you are using `where`.

You will either need to call `.first` on this to get the single object or call `.destroy_all`

I would recommend updating your query to use `find` instead so it returns a singular resource such as:

```
@interview_participant = InterviewParticipant.find_by_interview_id_and_participant_id(params[:interview_id], params[:participant_id])
```

so that you can call `.destroy` properly

Comment: Jason, thank you so much. I had tried lots of different ways to find by in_id AND part_id but I just didn't know about using find_by_interview_id_and_participant_id as a helper. I guess I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Just a reminder: finders based on `find_by` will be deprecated in Rails 4. The safest route is `where` + `first`.

Comment: @depa I think that find_by is the only one sticking around actually http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

has this changed?

Comment: Interesting. I was relying on this blog post, but Edge Guides are a better source. http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013